# how to split mailsytem based on condition

Tags: 7, emails

I have a site for sending newsletters and I want to send through two mail system. I was using mandrill mail and PepiPost mail service. If I want to send a newsletter to 100 users, I need to use mandrill mail system for 50 users and pepiPost mail system for 50 users. How can I achieve it?